# Find and replace text from a large txt file on ubuntu

Tags: json, ubuntu

I want to replace "}{" by "},{" to make a large txt file into valid json. Need help !!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with sed:

```
sed -i 's/}{/},{/g' filename
```

`sed` is the command, `-i` implies that the changes have to made to a file, which name you're giving at the end (and you should change `filename`, of course).

The substitution part starts with the `s`, between the first `//`, you set what you want to replace, between the last `//`, you set what you want instead. The `g` at the end makes sure that this search/replace is not only executed once, but as long as `sed` finds matches.

If you have any newlines present after the `}`, you can simply remove them all, you'll still get a valid JSON afterwards:

```
cat filename | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/}{/},{/g' >newfilename
```

This would simply delete all newlines (`\n`) and pass it to the command. It will create a new file, though.

Comment: really thanks your help, but the real problem is "}{" is not present in same  line i.e "{" is present at the new line.

Comment: @ChandanBasantTiwari I've updated my answer. This won't be as elegant as it can be, but it will work. If you need the JSON pretty-printed afterwards, you can use `jq` for that.